# Aprendendo a usar AJAX em ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html5, asp.net-mvc-5, ajax

Em meu projeto, tenho dois *models* diferentes, gerando com isso, seus *controllers* e suas views. Só que o acontece é que eu não sei usar AJAX e precisava urgentemente de uma ajuda de vocês. O que acontece é que, eu queria renderizar as views de um *controller* em uma *view* de outro *controller*. Explicando melhor por exemplo, tenho um model, *controller* e views de Aluno e um model, *controller* e views de ocorrência. O que acontece, eu queria renderizar na *view* details dos alunos as ocorrências que ele tem e listá-las, adicionar uma nova e editar uma já existente. Ou seja, gravar informações da ocorrências sem precisar sair da *view* de detalhes do aluno. Sei que usando AJAX tenho como fazer isso, só que eu não to conseguindo achar artigos ou vídeos legais sobre. Toda vez que acho, fico mais confuso. Será que alguém poderia criar um exemplo básico pra que eu possa seguir e aprender a usar AJAX?

Comment: Mais alguma resposta ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ate podes ir por Jquery e fica mais simples:

```
$("#divOcorrencia").empty().load('/Aluno/Details');
```

Assim, crias uma `div` onde irá aparecer o detalhes dos alunos, e fazes `load` da função no controller que pretendes (neste caso, detalhes de alunos)

Se queres carregar uma view sem ir ao `controller` podes fazer:

```
@Html.Partial("/PastaViewsAlunos/Detials");
```

Exemplo de `Action` para carregar a `view` `Details`

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    var dadosAlunos = db.Alunos.ToList();
    return PartialView(dadosAlunos)
}
```

Esta função carrega a `view` `Detials` com os dados dos alunos (tens é de editar a `query` para colocar os dados que queres apresentar)

**EDIT**

O que te estou a tentar explicar em baixo é o seguinte:

Tens uma view principal onde vai levar as partials com a informação que queres (no caso, alunos e ocorrencias)

POR JAVASCRIPT:

ViewComum.cshtml

```
<div id="divAlunos">
</div>

<div id="divOcorrencias">
</div>

<script>
    $("#divAlunos").empty().load('/Aluno/Details');
    $("#divOcorrencias").empty().load('/Ocorrencias/Details');
</script>
```

Controller:
/Aluno/Details

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    var dadosAlunos = db.Alunos.ToList();
    return PartialView(dadosAlunos)
}
```

/Ocorrencias/Details

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    var dadosOc = db.Ocorrencias.ToList();
    return PartialView(dadosOc)
}
```

PartialView Alunos:

```
@model List<BDOleoTorres.Models.Alunos>
//Aqui constrois a tua partial com os dados dos alunos que queres
```

PartialView Ocorrencias:

```
@model List<BDOleoTorres.Models.Ocorrencias>
//Aqui constrois a tua partial com os dados dos ocorrencuas que queres
```

Comment: Entendi e ai eu colocaria nesses partials os dados que me interessa certo ? Mas na hora puxar eles, eu poderia puxar um partial de ocorrencias no partial de alunos sem problema nenhum ? Ou eu teria que criar um terceiro partial pra puxar as informações necessárias ?

Comment: Sim, nessas partials podes usar os dados que interessa. Queres usar Ocorrencias com Alunos na mesma tabela? Tudo misturado? Sem sim, aconselho a criar um ViewModel comum, onde misturas os dados de ambos

Comment: ViewModel você fala é uma view que não é tipada certo ? Onde eu misturo os dados que quero pegar.

Comment: Não, ViewModel é tipo uma entidade (ou tabela, como quiseres chamar), onde constróis os campos que queres. Fazes um ViewModel com os dados dos Alunos e das Ocorrências e fica resolvido. Atenção que um ViewModel não pertence à base de dados

Comment: Como que eu faria esse ViewModel ? Algum exemplo ? E como que faço pra que ele não seja mapeado no banco ? Então depois que eu fizesse esse viewmodel as views seriam geradas automaticamente junto com o controller ?

Comment: Acho que já não estás a perceber nada do que estou para aqui a explicar. Já apresentei uma solução possível (não percebendo se é bem o que queres ou não). Faz outro post, é melhor

Comment: Não não. Perdão, eu pergunto demais. Vou tentar fazer aqui. Já ta aqui, então vou implementar. Caso eu tenha algum erro ou coisa do tipo, eu volto a postar aqui ! Muito obrigado.